# Не работает передача данных между php-скриптами

Tags: php

Есть скрипт, который работает на поддомене и собирает на нём данные при помощи ajax, после чего отправляет их другому php-файлу уже на основном домене на обработку и валидацию, но там происходит ошибка **Undefined index: data in /engine/search.php**.

Файл, перенаправляющий данные:

```
require('../engine/functions.php');
$origin = getDomain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://search.' . $origin);
$data = $_POST['data'];
//var_dump($data);
if(isset($data) && !empty($data)) {
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'           => [
                "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"
            ],
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents('https://' . $origin . '/engine/search.php', false, $context);
    if ($result === false) { 
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
        die();
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo $result;
}
```

Данные в search.php принимаю при помощи `$data = $_POST['data'];`. В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить данные по ключу `data`, нужно их передавать с ключом `data`:

```
http_build_query(array('data' => $data))
```