# как передать несколько параметров через post

Tags: php

Есть код:

```
 $params = array
 ('http'=>array
     ('method'=> 'POST,
      'header'=> 'Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'content'=>'text=hello',
     )
  );
```

Как передать несколько параметров через **POST**, например `text, name, lang`?

Comment: `'content'=>'text=hello&name=Perkins&lang=ru'` ?

Comment: ^ ага, тоже самое хотел написать, ну или заранее засуньте это в какой-нибудь массив и передавайте его, может быть...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/630882/186083